# Xpages add a custom control that doesn't take up space (rendered versus loaded versus visible)

Tags: xpages

I have some custom controls that I want to include in Xpages, but I don't want them to be visible to the user or to take up space on the screen, as it is throwing my alignment off. I have looked at the properties rendered, loaded, and visible, but I don't really understand them and they don't seem to do what I want, which is to include some functionality but not change the layout.

I am sure there is a way to do this, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: What does the custom controls include that you want to include in an XPage? Perhaps there's another way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loaded means it won't be added to the component tree and only affects server-side functionality. Because it's not in the component tree (the server-side map of the page) it can't be passed to the browser or processed during partial refreshes. Rendered and visible are the same and mean they're in the component tree, so server-side processing can interact with them, but no HTML is passed to the browser for them. So you can't interact with them via CSJS. If you want it passed to the browser, available for CSJS but not visible to the user, you'll need to set the style as display:none. Another option is to put that style in a theme and allocate the themeId you choose to your custom control.